# Keep data on multiple form WindowsForms c#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I 'am making a WindowsForms application. I have 2 Forms :

- On the first form (`Form1`), There are many fields (Textboxs) that should be filled by the user, then click to a button (`Transfer`).
- This button should show all the input datas of `Form1` in a new  Form (`Form2`).

I'm not sure how to begin to move data from one form to another. Can somebody guide me how to do it?

Comment: Does  `Form1` create/own `Form2`, or are both forms present independently and do you need to update between them?

Comment: Yes, `Form1` create `Form2` but with the datas of the first

Answer (score 1):

If `Form1` creates `Form2` specifically to show the data, then you can use a non-default constructor to pass the information as you create the form.

First, let's consider an example of the information you want to transfer, and name it `Form2Info`:

```
// This class is an example of the information you want to transfer
public class Form2Info
{
    public string text1;
    public int number1;
}
```

Then, you modify `Form2`'s constructor to take the information:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form2Info info;

    public Form2(Form2Info information)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        info = information;
        // Do something with this information, such as populate a TextBox or Label on the form.
    }
}
```

Finally, you want to create a `Form2` instance from your `Form1`:

```
// Create the information you want to pass; we fill it with some placeholder data here.
Form2Info info = new Form2Info();
info.text1 = "Hello"
info.number1 = 5;
// Now create the form and pass the data
Form2 form2 = new Form2(info);
form2.ShowDialog(); // Show modal dialog.
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Textbox has a value (`Textbox.Text` property). You will have to transfer the content of these different properties to the new controls in your second form.

The easiest way will be through a custom Form constructor for the second form.

```
public Form2(string textBox1Value, string textBox2Value)
// etc... add as many as you like or use an object that holds all values in properties
{
    InitializeComponent(); // Required by WinForms

    this.TextBox1.Text = textBox1Value;
    this.TextBox2.Text = textBox2Value;
}
```

Make sure you match the text boxes you want using the names. Finally when creating the form on the `Transfer` button code, call this constructor instead.